# How to copy nupkg from build process to drop folder

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

**TL/DR: In a release step, how do I find a `.nupkg` file that was definitely created in a build process and copy it to a drop folder for use in a release task?**

Using TFS 2018, I am trying to copy a `.nupkg` file created in a prior Build task to the drop folder.

## ...In the Build Process...

From the log, I know that the file was created.

> Successfully created package
>   'C:\agent_work\9\a\StaticHelpers.1.0.0.nupkg'.

What I am trying to figure out is how I can find this file and copy it to the drop folder. Using [Build Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) for inspiration, I have tried the following. At first, I thought it was successful because of what the log said.

- Source Folder: `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
- Contents: `*\*.nupkg`
- Target Folder: `drop`
- Result:

> found 1 files Copying C:\agent_work\9\a\StaticHelpers.1.0.0.nupkg to
>   drop\a\StaticHelpers.1.0.0.nupkg

All that means is that I can create a release process that takes that file and copies it in a copy release step, right?

## ...In the Release Process...

Not right. There is nothing in the drop folder when I created a copy file release task and tried to select the nuget package that was definitely created in the build. What I need to do is take that `*.nupkg` file created during the Build process and copy it to a network share.

[image]

So I tried to hard-code the folder based on what I copied from the build log.

- Source Folder: `drop\a`

The release failed, showing this in the log:

> [error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: C:\agent_work\r4\a\drop

Either I am copying the file to the wrong location or I am reading from the wrong location. What folders do I need to use so that I can see the `*.nupkg` file in my release task?

Comment: Wait, are you using the **Publish Artifact** task in your build, or are you using the **Copy File** task? You should be publishing an artifact if you want to make an artifact available for a down-stream process.

Comment: I made the nuget package in the _Build_ process, followed by the Copy File task. In the _Release_ process I need to copy the nupkg file to a network share. I'll throw in some bold sections in my question to delineate the content better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build process, don't use a *Copy Files* task, use a *Publish Artifacts* task. That will publish an artifact "attached" to the build that a release will automatically pick up during deployment.